# boost::numeric_cast functionality without exception

Tags: c++, boost, casting

We would like to have a checked numeric conversion between two numeric types without triggering exception throwing on failure. Something like:

```
bool numeric_cast(Source s, Target &t)
```

The boost error handling is hooked in our project with generating call stack and some other expensive things. I have places where the failure of the conversion is likely and I don't want to pay that high price on every failure.

Comment: And what you want? Simplest way is to catch exception in your function and return false in this case.

Comment: If you don't want to call `numeric_cast` - you can look at boost headers and rewrite it...

Comment: @ForEveR As I said, generating the exception is expensive. I would like to avoid that cost. And I would prefer solutions which do not involve rewriting things as I'm not that good metaprogrammer. If everything else fails, I will do that.

Comment: Then there is only one way - look at boost headers and write `numeric_cast` without exceptions. It can be not simple, since `numeric_cast` is very complicate.

Comment: @Notinlist, and why is it expensive? Are you sure the bottleneck of your application are exceptions?

Comment: Every mainstream compiler uses zero-cost exceptions.

Comment: How many of the things are you expecting?

Comment: @Rapptz Last time I checked this wasn't true for MinGW, but this could have changed. And there is still the extra code that has to be generated, which has been the main motivation to introduce `noexcept`. So I reckon that there is a demand for such a thing as an exception free numeric_cast.

Comment: @Jefffrey Because we customized it to generate call-stack into it. We rarely throw exceptions as we are not using them for flow control.

Comment: @Rapptz zero-cost exceptions don't exist. It's the try-blocks that are zero-overhead in the non-throwing case. But 64-bit code usually actually has a (much) higher cost to actually throwing/handling an exception!

Comment: @pmr MinGW and GCC does have zero-cost exceptions (note: this means that the try-catch block have zero overhead, not the generation of the exception itself). Also, the motivation for `noexcept` is in regards to move constructors not generating less code. See [N3050](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3050.html).

Comment: What are you doing with exceptions if not flow control? I'm curious.

Comment: MinGW can generate DWARF and SEH exceptions. DWARF is zero-cost but SEH is not. The problem with DWARF is the poor interaction with code using SEH exceptions, such as VS's. On x64 they both use the x64 EH model, which is zero-cost and similar to DWARF. VS x86, however, uses SEH exceptions which are *not* zero-cost.

Comment: @Jefffrey I mean not normal/ordinary flow control. If we throw them they usually reach the surface (command line or GUI).

Comment: "I mean not normal/ordinary flow control" -- You mean for *exceptional* flow control?

Comment: @Jefffrey Yes, exceptional flow control. We may have a language barrier here. I wanted to express that we rarely throw exceptions. We use them for error handling. These error reports are constructed expensively and they usually reach the surface (command line or GUI). There is a place in our code where we expecting a numeric conversion to fail often and we want to deal with it locally. We don't want to generate the expensive error report and then just throw it away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I see from headers there is only one way to throw exception in `numeric_cast` - it's overflow.

You can write overflow_policy (or use `silent_overflow_handler` for this case). But you should write specialization for

```
template <typename Target, typename Source, typename EnableIf = void>
struct numeric_cast_traits
{
    typedef def_overflow_handler    overflow_policy;
    typedef UseInternalRangeChecker range_checking_policy;
    typedef Trunc<Source>           rounding_policy;
};
```

I'm not right... It looks to me, that it will be more simple to rewrite `numeric_cast` function really

```
template <typename Target, typename Source> 
inline Target numeric_cast( Source arg )
{
    typedef numeric::conversion_traits<Target, Source>   conv_traits;
    typedef numeric::numeric_cast_traits<Target, Source> cast_traits;
    typedef boost::numeric::converter
        <
            Target,
            Source, 
            conv_traits,
            typename cast_traits::overflow_policy, 
            typename cast_traits::rounding_policy, 
            boost::numeric::raw_converter< conv_traits >,
            typename cast_traits::range_checking_policy
        > converter;
    return converter::convert(arg);
}
```

It should look like

```
template <typename Target, typename Source> 
inline Target numeric_cast( Source arg )
{
    typedef numeric::conversion_traits<Target, Source>   conv_traits;
    typedef numeric::numeric_cast_traits<Target, Source> cast_traits;
    typedef boost::numeric::converter
        <
            Target,
            Source, 
            conv_traits,
            my_overflow_policy,
            typename cast_traits::rounding_policy,
            boost::numeric::raw_converter< conv_traits >,
            typename cast_traits::range_checking_policy
        > converter;
    return converter::convert(arg);
}
```

Also, you can define `BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS` and then it will simply `throw`, without `boost::throw_exception`.

Comment: We do want exceptions with own very expensive implementations (we generate call-stack into them). On the upper part: Can you please add more detailed instructions for that?